# Share-buttons causing styling error on mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<div class="social-share"> 
<span class="st_facebook_large"></span> 
<span class="st_twitter_large"></span> 
<span class="st_email_large"></span> 
<span class="st_sharethis_large"></span> 
<span class="st_plusone_button_large"></span> 
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.social-share {
position:absolute;
z-index:0 !important;
}
.image {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;  
}
```

The CSS above is customed so that a image next to the share-buttons wont interfere with them.

It is causing this styling error on the mobile device:

[image]

I am thinking on doing something like this but it is not working:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .social-share {
     margin-bottom: 17px;
  }
}
```

[URL to the scenario](http://www.shopstuff.se/produkt/woo-ninja-3/)

Question: How do I solve the styling error on the mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the Position:relative to the div containing class="social-share"

Comment: You can do it by giving media query

Comment: Hi Thanks it worked and since you answerd first I will accept your answer first. No need for media query.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the use of "position: absolute;" which causes the margin not to work. You need to change this to "position: relative;" and you'll see that the margin works properly. No need for media queries for this specific issue.

Comment: Your idea worked perfectly. Thank you. I did not have to do any media queries for this.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help. If you can mark my answer as your accepted answer it is appreciated to help me build my reputation on the site :)

Comment: Hi Brock, @Milind Rajput was the first one to write it so I have to accept his answer.

Comment: No problem Joneskvist, I didn't realize that you had already chosen an accepted answer :)

Comment: But your good explanation definitely deserves a thumbs up :)!